# Imagecreatefrompng() - Connection was reset error

Tags: php, image, function, imagecreatefrompng

I have installed a piece of code on a website, wich includes gd functions.
After debugging I came to a conclusion that the

```
$src = imagecreatefrompng($s);
```

is causing the server to respond: "Connection was reset"
Even if I change the code to:

```
$src = @imagecreatefrompng($s);
```

The same error occurs.
I have checked the php version, checked if gd library is installed and enabled, but everything is ok. There is nothing in the error_log.
Also, the file path is all right, the file exists, and other functions can access the file (like fopen or file_get_contents), so there is no problem with the rights.

Anyone has an idea?

Edit:
The file is on a local server.

Comment: Hey Ernest, this doesn't really sound like anything that could be caused by GD. Could you try writing a basic GD php file to see if the problem still persists? try something like the sample from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Comment: Do you get the image from a remote server? If so, you should use `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($s));` first. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

Comment: Shai Mishali: I have tried the first example from the site you linked, and the result was successful.

Comment: Quasdunk - The file is on the local server.

Comment: @ErnestMarcinko Please can you ensure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of the script and see if you get any more useful error messages

Comment: @DaveRandom - Nothing happens, no error messages, just the connection reset error.

Comment: Is that a PHP error, or the output of your script? I.e. where do you see the string error "Connection was reset", and what is the FULL string?

Comment: @DaveRandom - It's not like a php error, it's a server error, like when you open a domain wich does not exists.
Like this: http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/127/f/7/the_connection_was_reset_by_s3k4rep-d3fs7ze.png

Comment: Oh like an actual HTTP error? That is interesting, it suggests that PHP has just crashed - can you run the script from the command line? If so, try it and see what you get (if it is a *nix server I suspect you may see the string `SIGSEGV` if the script is dying with no error) - if this is the case it may due to a corrupted input file - can you open the image in an image viewer on your PC?

Comment: @DaveRandom - Unfortunately I cannot access the server by command line. I have double checked the image file, and it's not corrupted.
I contacted the server administrator to reinstall gd and php, it may solve the problem. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: @ErnestMarcinko How large is the image file you are trying to open? It may also help to add the code surrounding the way that you call `imagecreatefrompng()` to the question - notably how you are constructing `$s`, whether the code is called in a loop, function etc - if you can add the relevant code block to the question we can look at it and see if there are any obvious errors, although from what you say I doubt this is the case and I suspect that the problem is an internal PHP one. What version of PHP/GD is the server currently running? (`phpinfo()`)

Comment: @DaveRandom
GD - bundled (2.0.34 compatible) 
PHP - Version 5.3.9
The image size is 1x56 px, not corrupted, png, not in a loop, the function is called one time.
$s is 100% okay, I tested it with fopen, file_get_contents, printed it out, also checked manually if the file really exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, if you can't access the server via command line you may have some headaches tracking this down.  2 things that come to mind:

1. It's unlikely, yet possible [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) is not installed, or **gd** wasn't compiled w/ PNG support.  Run [phpinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) from the browser and look for the **gd** section, you should see *PNG support 'enabled'* there.
2. The image might not be a PNG image!  I know it's wacky but these things can happen, just naming a file *.png* does not a PNG file make, haha.  If you have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) you can use the [identify](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php?ImageMagick=p2mug599sceo1artqff210h8k7) program to check, here's a run from my laptop:

   $ identify ~/transparent-pixel.png
   ~/transparent-pixel.png PNG 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 2.79KB 0.010u 0:00.009

There are probly some other programs you can use to verify the image is indeed an PNG.

Lastly, I would suggest getting your script to work in a local environment that simulates the server, like a VM or similar.  That should help you track down the issue on the server w/o quite as many headaches.